# Does classical axial current conservation prevent the spontaneous emission of a photon by an electron?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-spin

I understand the axial current conservation (in the massless limit) in classial field theory to mean that the difference between right handed and left handed electrons is conserved in QED.

$$j^{\mu 5}~:=~\overline{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^5\psi~=~j^{\mu}_R-j^{\mu}_L,\qquad
j^{\mu}_{R,L}~:=~ \overline{\psi}_{R,L}\gamma^{\mu}\psi_{R,L},  $$

How does it relate to spontaneous photon emission ? When an excited electron emits a photon, its spin flips. This would mean that the axial charge for fermions changes. Is this process supressed for massless electrons ?